# Modal is not taking height in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to the jquery modal popup.When I click on the hyperlink modal is opening fine.But height is not taking.i could not figured it out.I have googled and tried something but it is not working.But i tried to Posting the question giving modal is not a function error.Please any one can help me Thanks in Advance.

### Html Code

```js
   
function OpenModal() {
  $("#divModal").dialog({
    autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Material', width: '1190',height: "460;"
    , buttons: { Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
  }).dialog('open');
  return false;
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>

table {
          width:100%;
          border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      td {
          border: 1px solid black;
      }
       th{

        text-align: center;
        font-size:15px;

      }
</style>
<div style="width:60%;float:right;margin:5px 0px;">
  <a style="padding-right:50px;" onclick="javascript:OpenModal();" href="#"><i style="padding-left:65%;margin:6px 0;"class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span  class="title">Add Material</span>
   </a>

         <div style="display:none;" id="divModal">
           <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
             <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
              <div style="float:left;width:10%;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;margin:17px 0px 0px 10px;">
                   <label>Name</label>
               </div>
               <div style="float:left;width:81%;margin-top:17px;padding-left:20px;">
                   <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="mtrlid" value=""/>
                   <input type="text" class="nameupper" id="name" name="name" value="" style="width:98.5%;height:20px;font-size:17px;background-color:#F5F5DC;" required/>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div style="width:49%;float:right;">
               <div style="float:left;width:8%;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;margin:19px 0px 0px 0px;">
                   <label>UOM</label>
               </div>
               <div style="float:left;width:30%;margin-top:17px;padding-left:10.5%; ">
                   <input type="text" id="uom" name="uom" value="" style="width:75%;height:20px;font-size:17px;direction:rtl;" required/>
               </div>


               <div style="float:left;width:12%;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;margin:19px 0px 0px 10px;">
                   <label>Price</label>
               </div>
                <div style="float:left;width:26%;margin-top:17px;margin-left:10%;">
                   <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="" style="width:73%;height:20px;font-size:17px;direction:rtl;" required/>
               </div>

           </div>
         </div>

         <div style="clear:both;width:100%;">
         <div style="width:49%;float:left;margin-top:10px;">

         <div class="lb1" style="float:left; width:13.4%;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;margin:4px 0px 0px 7px;">
         <label>Serial No</label>
         </div>
         <div class="txt1" style="float:left;width:32%;padding-left:4px;">
         <input type="text"  id="serialno" value="" name="slno"  style="width:95%;height:20px;font-size:17px;direction:RTL;" />
         </div>
         <div class="lb1" style="float:left; width:17%;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;font-size:17px;margin:4px 0px 0px 7px;padding-left:10px;">
         <label>Max Stock</label>
         </div>
         <div class="txt1" style="float:left;width:28.5%;padding-left:15px;">
         <input type="text" id="maxstk" value="" name="mxstk"  style="width:95%;height:20px;font-size:17px;direction:RTL;" />
         </div>

         </div>


         <div style="width:50%;float:right;height:10px;margin-top:10px;">

         <div class="lbl" style="float:left; width:17%;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;margin-top:4px;padding-left:8px;">
         <label>Current Stock</label>
         </div>

         <div class="txt1" style="float:left;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;width:25%;margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
         <input type="text" id="crtstk" value="" name="crtstock" style="width:90%;height:20px;font-size:17px;direction:RTL;" />
         </div>
         <div class="lbl" style="float:left;font-size:16px;font-family:arial; width:20%;text-align:left;font-size:16px;margin-top:4px;margin-left:36px; ">
         <label>Stock On Order</label>
         </div>
         <div class="txt1" style="float:left;width:20%;">
         <input type="text" id="stostk" value="" name="stkonorder" style="width:95%;height:20px;font-size:17px;margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;direction:RTL;" />
         </div>

         </div>

         </div>
         <div style="text-align:center;float:left;width:14%;height:5%;margin:20px 0 0 35%;position:absolute;top:450px;">
             <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Save" value="Save" />
             <input type="reset" id="reset" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
         </div>
            <!-- <iframe id="myIframe" src="SomeValidURL" width="1100" height="800" /> -->
        </div>

   <!-- <form action="#" method="post">
   <div style="padding-left:60%;" class="search-box" style="width:10%;float:left;margin:10px 0px 10px 60%;"></div><div style="float:right;padding-right:30px;"><label>Search</label><input name="search" style="height:30px;" id="search" type="search" autocomplete="off;"></div>
   <!- <input type="submit" name="button"> -->
 <!-- </form>  -->
</div>
<div style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;" max-height="500px;" overflow="auto;">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;padding-top:20px;" id="Mytbl">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>UOM</th>
  <th>Maxstock</th>
  <th>Current Stock</th>
  <th>Edit</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
          <td>Iron Sticks</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>1700</td>
      <td>160</td>
      <td><a href="http://localhost/Building/Buildingcontroller/editdata/1"><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></a></td>
      <td><a class="removedata" href="1"><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a></td>
    </tr>
          <td>Cement Bags</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>1400</td>
      <td>120</td>
      <td><a href="http://localhost/Building/Buildingcontroller/editdata/5"><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></a></td>
      <td><a class="removedata" href="5"><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a></td>
    </tr>
          <td>Iron Stick</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>1500</td>
      <td>1600</td>
      <td><a href="http://localhost/Building/Buildingcontroller/editdata/4"><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></a></td>
      <td><a class="removedata" href="4"><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User only `height:460` instead of `height: "460px;"` please check working snippet below.

```js
function OpenModal() {
           $("#divModal").dialog({
               autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Material', width: '1190',height:460
               , buttons: { Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
           }).dialog('open');
           return false;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>

table {
          width:100%;
          border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      td {
          border: 1px solid black;
      }
       th{

        text-align: center;
        font-size:15px;

      }
</style>
<div style="width:60%;float:right;margin:5px 0px;">
  <a style="padding-right:50px;" onclick="javascript:OpenModal();" href="#"><i style="padding-left:65%;margin:6px 0;"class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span  class="title">Add Material</span>
   </a>

         <div style="display:none;" id="divModal">
           <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
             <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
              <div style="float:left;width:10%;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;margin:17px 0px 0px 10px;">
                   <label>Name</label>
               </div>
               <div style="float:left;width:81%;margin-top:17px;padding-left:20px;">
                   <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="mtrlid" value=""/>
                   <input type="text" class="nameupper" id="name" name="name" value="" style="width:98.5%;height:20px;font-size:17px;background-color:#F5F5DC;" required/>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div style="width:49%;float:right;">
               <div style="float:left;width:8%;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;margin:19px 0px 0px 0px;">
                   <label>UOM</label>
               </div>
               <div style="float:left;width:30%;margin-top:17px;padding-left:10.5%; ">
                   <input type="text" id="uom" name="uom" value="" style="width:75%;height:20px;font-size:17px;direction:rtl;" required/>
               </div>


               <div style="float:left;width:12%;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;margin:19px 0px 0px 10px;">
                   <label>Price</label>
               </div>
                <div style="float:left;width:26%;margin-top:17px;margin-left:10%;">
                   <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="" style="width:73%;height:20px;font-size:17px;direction:rtl;" required/>
               </div>

           </div>
         </div>

         <div style="clear:both;width:100%;">
         <div style="width:49%;float:left;margin-top:10px;">

         <div class="lb1" style="float:left; width:13.4%;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;margin:4px 0px 0px 7px;">
         <label>Serial No</label>
         </div>
         <div class="txt1" style="float:left;width:32%;padding-left:4px;">
         <input type="text"  id="serialno" value="" name="slno"  style="width:95%;height:20px;font-size:17px;direction:RTL;" />
         </div>
         <div class="lb1" style="float:left; width:17%;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;font-size:17px;margin:4px 0px 0px 7px;padding-left:10px;">
         <label>Max Stock</label>
         </div>
         <div class="txt1" style="float:left;width:28.5%;padding-left:15px;">
         <input type="text" id="maxstk" value="" name="mxstk"  style="width:95%;height:20px;font-size:17px;direction:RTL;" />
         </div>

         </div>


         <div style="width:50%;float:right;height:10px;margin-top:10px;">

         <div class="lbl" style="float:left; width:17%;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;margin-top:4px;padding-left:8px;">
         <label>Current Stock</label>
         </div>

         <div class="txt1" style="float:left;font-size:16px;font-family:arial;width:25%;margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
         <input type="text" id="crtstk" value="" name="crtstock" style="width:90%;height:20px;font-size:17px;direction:RTL;" />
         </div>
         <div class="lbl" style="float:left;font-size:16px;font-family:arial; width:20%;text-align:left;font-size:16px;margin-top:4px;margin-left:36px; ">
         <label>Stock On Order</label>
         </div>
         <div class="txt1" style="float:left;width:20%;">
         <input type="text" id="stostk" value="" name="stkonorder" style="width:95%;height:20px;font-size:17px;margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;direction:RTL;" />
         </div>

         </div>

         </div>
         <div style="text-align:center;float:left;width:14%;height:5%;margin:20px 0 0 35%;position:absolute;top:450px;">
             <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Save" value="Save" />
             <input type="reset" id="reset" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
         </div>
            <!-- <iframe id="myIframe" src="SomeValidURL" width="1100" height="800" /> -->
        </div>

   <!-- <form action="#" method="post">
   <div style="padding-left:60%;" class="search-box" style="width:10%;float:left;margin:10px 0px 10px 60%;"></div><div style="float:right;padding-right:30px;"><label>Search</label><input name="search" style="height:30px;" id="search" type="search" autocomplete="off;"></div>
   <!- <input type="submit" name="button"> -->
 <!-- </form>  -->
</div>
<div style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;" max-height="500px;" overflow="auto;">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;padding-top:20px;" id="Mytbl">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>UOM</th>
  <th>Maxstock</th>
  <th>Current Stock</th>
  <th>Edit</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
          <td>Iron Sticks</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>1700</td>
      <td>160</td>
      <td><a href="http://localhost/Building/Buildingcontroller/editdata/1"><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></a></td>
      <td><a class="removedata" href="1"><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a></td>
    </tr>
          <td>Cement Bags</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>1400</td>
      <td>120</td>
      <td><a href="http://localhost/Building/Buildingcontroller/editdata/5"><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></a></td>
      <td><a class="removedata" href="5"><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a></td>
    </tr>
          <td>Iron Stick</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>1500</td>
      <td>1600</td>
      <td><a href="http://localhost/Building/Buildingcontroller/editdata/4"><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></a></td>
      <td><a class="removedata" href="4"><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you i got it now.for height there is no quotes.